# How to access files from a different network then where PHP is saved?

Tags: php, cmd

I am currently working on a network called \\Luke\ which is where PHP is installed on.  I need to be able to count the lines on a file located on a separate server called \\Leia\ .  I have tried using CMD commands from my PHP file to perform this task, but I am not able to access files outside of \\Luke.  From my research, this seems to be intended, PHP cant access files outside of the web directory where its saved. Due to constraints on a project, I cant install PHP onto \\Leia\ .  If anyone has any suggestions on how I might be able to perform this task, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
$download_path = '\\\Leia\practice.txt';
exec('findstr "." '.$download_path.' | find /c /v "" 2>&1',$output,$status);
echo "Number of Lines: ".$output[0]."<br>";
```

Comment: ` PHP cant access files outside of the web directory where its saved` That's not true by default, although it can be configured. What error messages are you getting exactly? Can you show some code? Any special reason for using  command-line commands when you could open the file directly in PHP?

Comment: I posted the gist of the code I am using above.  I originally was just opening and reading from the file before the constraints on the project got changed and I had to read from Leia instead of Luke.  I dont have to use CMD at all, it was just suggested as an option by someone I was working with.   Thanks for the response.

Comment: OK, but what errors are you getting? There is a syntax error on the first line, the string is missing quotes. Is that the exact code you are using?

Comment: Its not exactly what I am using, I just tried to pick out the main parts to get back to you faster.  The errors that I am getting are either "Cannot Open \\Leia\practice.txt Access is denied" or "The system cannot find the drive specified.  I think Steve answered why I am getting these errors.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server based language that allows you to run code on the server so that the client (a remote browser) doesn't have direct access to your server content.  Only information that your PHP program writes out is visible.  However while your PHP code is running it has access within your server.  If your server can mount a drive on another system, or has authority to do queries or other requests on the other system (Leia in your example), then you can do what you want.

PHP itself doesn't stop you from accessing other systems.  For example, you might be doing database queries in your PHP program where the database is on a different machine than your web server.  That's possible because your server has authority to access the database within the network.

Comment: I will look into what exactly Luke has access to, and will see if I can change it to access Leia.  This really helped me understand more of what is going on, I appreciate it.